# How to include text from a dataframe as heading or paragraph?

Tags: r, knitr

I am using `knitr` to produce a dynamic HTML website. I would like to include text from a dataframe as normal text.

```
#my dataframe
text 
my first paragraph
my second paragraph
```

In knitr I can use `cat()` or `print()`, but they generate ugly chunks in R output style.

```
{r 
   cat(text)
   print(text)
}
```

Is it possible to output the text/strings with a "normal paragraph" style just like when writing markdown?

Or is it faster or easier to create a new theme?

Update: I am looping over the dataframe `df`:

```
variable1, variable2, text
2, 10, hello
5, 11, hi

for (i in unique(df$text) {
    p <- ggplot(df, aes(variable1, variable2)) + geom_point()

   cat(df$text)
   print(p)


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following chunk:

````
```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
cat(paste("<p>", df$text, "</p>"), sep = "\n")
```
````

Here, all strings in `df$text` are included in a `p` tag (HTML paragraph). The argument `results='asis'` allows for interpreting the result as HTML (not an R output chunk).

As a result all strings in `df$text` will appear as separate paragraphs.

Comment: I am looping over the dataframe. I guess, it's not possible to use this method without breaking the loop

Comment: @kbrunner Please add a small reproducible example.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you, Sven!